# How to generate a random index into my ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, random, nullpointerexception

So I have a class Cup which is part of a game for class. The public int select() method has to return a move in c. I need to generate a random index into c, and I'm told to do this by generating a random number from zero up to and not including the size of the ArrayList. Here's what I have:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
public class Cup {

    ArrayList<Integer> c = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private Random r;

    public Cup() {
        c.add(1);
        c.add(2);
        c.add(3);
        Random r = new Random();
    }

    public int count() {
        return c.size();
    }

    public int select() {
        int index = r.nextInt(c.size());
        return c.get(index);
    }

    public void remove(int m) {
        c.remove(m);
    }
}
```

When I compile this in the game I'm using, it compiles correctly but tells me there's a Null Pointer exception on the line where r.nextInt(c.size()) is. Just very confusing because I feel like this should be right. Thank you!!!

Comment: This line in the constructor `Random r = new Random();` is a local variable `r` and thus the instance variable `r` is never initialized, retaining its default `null` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your constructor you dont need `Random r` as you already have a `private Random r;`

The rest seems to be working. Take care about your `remove(int m)` method so the user doesn't pass a value greater than the ArrayList's size, to avoid an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Cup {

    ArrayList<Integer> c = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private Random r;

    public Cup() {
        c.add(1);
        c.add(2);
        c.add(3);

        //here you should use your r attribute
        r = new Random();
    }

    public int count() {
        return c.size();
    }

    public int select() {
        int index = r.nextInt(c.size());
        return c.get(index);
    }

    public void remove(int m) {
        c.remove(m);
    }
}
```

Comment: Got it, that was tripping me up. Thanks so much